# WPF DataGrid shows dot instead comma

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

After digging on the internet and searching for answers without result, I would like to ask you for help. I have a SQL database table with 2 columns (float datatype e.g 1,2 1,3 1,4 etc.)

[image: like this]

which are bound to a `DataGrid`

[image: like this].

XAML code:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="Tab_LosTab_PolterTab_PoltersektionViewSource" Source="{Binding Tab_Polter_Tab_Poltersektion, Source={StaticResource Tab_LosTab_PolterViewSource}}"/>

<DataGrid x:Name="Tab_PoltersektionDataGrid" IsReadOnly="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Tab_LosTab_PolterTab_PoltersektionViewSource}}" Margin="10,250,10,60" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Polter_H_vornColumn" Binding="{Binding Polter_H_vorn}" Header="Polterhöhe vorn" Width="*"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Polter_H_hintenColumn" Binding="{Binding Polter_H_hinten}" Header="Polterhöhe hinten" Width="*"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

and Vb.Net code:

```
Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded
    Dim DataSet1Tab_PoltersektionTableAdapter As PV.DataSet1TableAdapters.Tab_PoltersektionTableAdapter = New PV.DataSet1TableAdapters.Tab_PoltersektionTableAdapter()
    DataSet1Tab_PoltersektionTableAdapter.Fill(DataSet1.Tab_Poltersektion)
    Dim Tab_LosTab_PolterTab_PoltersektionViewSource As System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource = CType(Me.FindResource("Tab_LosTab_PolterTab_PoltersektionViewSource"), System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)
    Tab_LosTab_PolterTab_PoltersektionViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst()
End Sub
```

My problem is that my `DataGrid` displays those values this way: 1.2 1.3 1.4 where I need them to be displayed like this: 1,2 1,3 1,4 etc. When I try to edit some value and type 1,2 it returns 12. My PC language preferences are set as a European. Any advice?

Comment: Welcome in the culture hell. I guess the european culture is german?

Comment: yes it´s german

Comment: [This page](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/ecefc66d-d8ab-40ef-a6c1-600e6e71e9f2/decimal-formatting-in-datagridview-using-comma-as-decimal-separator?forum=winforms) might help you get some ideas. I particularly like setting the cultureInfo post.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `IValueConverter` to handle this.

```
public class GermanNumberConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((float)value).ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE"));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return float.Parse(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

And in your xaml code you use this converter like

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Polter_H_hinten, Converter={StaticResource GermanNumberConverter}}" />
```

You have to specify the converter in your `Window`, too.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <c:GermanNumberConverter x:Key="GermanNumberConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```